# query and importrange function with condition btween two date and sort in order

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I want to set query and importrange formula where i want the new sheet to show date that fall into today and yesterday date only and sort in ascending date and time

=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xk0Cvafixr5dayJkBkrzlYLFoA4E_PHYfPNQis12rc8/edit#gid=1702961582","CONSOLIDATE!A1:H"),"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col8 where Col1 <= date '"&text(B1,"yyyy-mm-dd")"' and >= date '"&text(B2,"yyyy-mm-dd")"' and order by Col1,Col2")")"

[image]

Comment: Hi!  If the answer below has solved your problem, please remember to Click the Tick, and accept it:  This helps anyone else with the same issue, arriving here from a Search Page, to what they need to do! :¬)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of syntax errors, should be:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xk0Cvafixr5dayJkBkrzlYLFoA4E_PHYfPNQis12rc8/edit#gid=1702961582","CONSOLIDATE!A1:H"),"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col8 where Col1 <= date '"&text(B1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and Col1>= date '"&text(B2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' order by Col1,Col2")
```

i.e. remember to put '&' after the date as well as before, but don't put 'and' before order by.